# How can I get all author written content?

Tags: author, sql

I have a site that needs two different tabs:
1. all author written content (Posts, comments, CTP)
2. all author *followed*  content (categories, taxonomies, other users content)

For the first all I could come up with was using unoion on wp_comments and wp_posts filtered by author sorted by date

Have no idea how to do the 2nd one...

Would love some advice

Comment: How are you tracking "_followed_ content"?

Comment: I have user metadata that contains folowed-users IDs, followed-tax IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution for #1. using WP_Query I can specify multiple post_type and an author ID. which gives all author written data...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very detailed or very clear but [`get_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) will return all of the user metadata for a user. That should have all of your fields.

You could also use `get_users` for the second tab. I am not dealing with the first since you state that your "have no idea how to do the 2nd one"

```
$args = array(
   'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
   'orderby' => 'nicename',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'who' => 0, // all users greater than subscriber
   // 'include' => array(1,2,3), // particular users
   // 'role' => 'rolename'
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

You could also use `WP_User_Query` directly.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query